# Using GDB to Debug VM Running on XEN Hypervisor

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, kernel, xen

I always used `GDB` to do kernel debug. Normally I would run the target kernel inside a `VM` and run `GDB` from the host machine. Currently I am working on a project where I need to use `XEN` hypervisor and I am in a situation where I feel the need to debug a `DOM-U` from `DOM-0`. After some searching I couldn't find a way to use `GDB` in this scenario. Is it possible to use `GDB` to debug a guest VM running in `XEN`? If not, what other alternatives I could use?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a pipe (for example, `/tmp/mydebug.pipe`), then have this line in the .conf file for your domU:

```
 serial = 'pipe:/tmp/mydebug.pipe'
```

Then you can simply use a tool such as WinDBG from another domU. See `mkfifo`.

Other possibly useful links:

https://xenserver.org/partners/developing-products-for-xenserver/18-sdk-development/135-xs-dev-windbg.html

http://www-archive.xenproject.org/files/xensummit_intel09/xen-debugging.pdf

https://www.slideshare.net/xen_com_mgr/from-printk-to-qemu-xenlinux-kernel-debugging